# trouble getting Id from firestore, using only arrayContains

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Having trouble getting Id from firestore, using only arrayContains. I need to get top level Id of the collection, which has sub-collection. Here is the picture[image: picture]

The id needed is underlined with blue. My code below returns 0 documents. Although, the users IDs are there. If I use arrayContainsAny => then chat messages with other users are returned. Pls, help! Thanks in advance! Printing 'chatId' returns 'newChat', no matter what I try.

```
TextButton(
  onPressed: () async {
    await ServerAPI().chatsCollection
        .where('users', arrayContains: [FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid,
      widget.outletId])
        .get().then((value) {
      setState(() {
         value.docs.isEmpty ?
         chatId = "newChat"
             : chatId = value.docs.first.id;
      });
      debugPrint('${widget.outletId}, ${chatId}');
    });
      Get.to(() => ChatScreen(chatId: chatId, senderId: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid,
    receiverId: widget.outletId));
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`arrayContains` operator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#dart_6) expects a single value as its parameter, and it returns document where an item in the array matches the value you pass. So in your case it looks for an array **item** that is itself the array you pass, which isn't the case in the screenshot you shared.

---

I think you might be looking for the [`arrayContainsAny` operator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_not-in_and_array-contains-any), which takes an array parameter and then matches documents where the array in the document contains any of the values that you pass.

---

If you actually want to return documents where the array contains **both** UID values, that would require an `arrayContainsAll` operator, which does not exist. You *may* be able to use a regular `isEqualTo` if (and only if) you have the UID values in the same order as the document stored them.

Alternative consider storing the UID in an additional map-field too:

```
usersMap: {
  "cgCiJ...": true,
  "oCx6k...": true
}
```

With this structure in place, you can now use two `isEqualTo` conditions to match the UID values.

Comment: thank you @Frank for the suggestion, but if I user arrayContainsAny, it returns different chats, chats that the user (not me, but my chat receipient, here as widget.outletId) has with other users... any way I can get Id without going through 2 streams? or hard matching the values?

Comment: First off, does the explanation I gave in the first half of my answer make sense? Does it explain why your current approach doesn't work? --- I wrote some extra information in my answer on another alternative that might be what you're looking for.

Comment: thank u! that is a great idea to store inseparate map or use the isEqualTo!!! why havent I though of it before? Also, the order... Thanks!